# Make MATLAB release GPU when CUDA fails

Tags: matlab, cuda, resources, mex, resource-cleanup

I write CUDA code that I call from MATLAB MEX files. I am not using any of MATLABs GPU libraries or capabilities. My code its just CUDA code that accepts C type variables and I only use mex to convert from `mwtypes` to C types, then call independent self-written CUDA code.

The problem is that sometimes, specially in development phase, CUDA fails (because I made a mistake). Most CUDA calls are generally surrounded by a call to `gpuErrchk(cudaDoSoething(cuda))`, [defined as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api):

```
// Uses MATLAB functions but you get the idea.
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        mexPrintf("GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort){
            //cudaDeviceReset(); //This does not make MATLAB release it
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MEX:myfun", ".");
        }
    }
}
```

While this works as expected, giving errors such as

> GPUassert: an illegal memory access was encountered somefile.cu 208

In most cases MATLAB does not release the GPU afterwards. Meaning that even if I change the code and recompile, the next call of the code will result in error:

> GPUassert: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
>   somefile.cu firs_cuda_line

The only way of removing this error is restarting MATLAB. This is just annoying and hinders the development/testing process. This is not what happens when I develop in say Visual Studio.

I have tried to `cudaDeviceReset()` both before and after the error has been raised, but to no avail.

**What can I do/try to make MATLAB release the GPU after a GPU runtime error?**

Comment: How are you creating the CUDA context your code is using?

Comment: If none of MATLAB's GPU libraries are in use, then it is not MATLAB that needs to release the GPU.

Comment: @talonmies How as in you want the code or general description? In short I have a .cu file with a "main". This only accepts C types, and outputs C types. Everything CUDA (memcpy, free, kernels, etc) happens in this file.  MATLAB has, in theory, no knowledge of it using CUDA (just for compilation where I link `nvcc` compiler to MVS in mex). The only MATLAB code in this file is the one showed, to error and print.

Comment: No how as in are you using lazy context establishment or are you doing explicit context management via the runtime API, or some combination of the two.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed, that Is why I tried some random stabs in the dark such as the `cudaDeviceReset()`. The fact is however that when I take the file and put it in a MVS project, create a mock C input data and run it, this does not happen.

Comment: Your question really is about cleaning up CUDA resources after an error, with the fact that you are writing a DLL somewhat relevant, and the fact the DLL is called from MATLAB is really beside the point and not worth a tag.

Comment: @BenVoigt lets see that after we find a solution ;)

Comment: @talonmies lazy context management, if I understand correctly. I dont select the GPU, nor I reset it (I do free the memory though).

Comment: For sure it is important whether the host application exits, ending the process, or keeps running.  Which host application, isn't a critical detail.

Comment: @BenVoigt I had this exact conversation 4  days ago in another post. Mods decide to leave the tag as it *may* be relevant. Unless you do know the solution, the fact that is MATLAB may be the source ( as I can only reproduce it there)

Comment: Fair enough regarding the tag, but I strongly advise that when researching the problem, you also do some searches about error recovery when using CUDA in a DLL -- without MATLAB as a search keyword -- because you'll almost certainly find more information that way.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, I did, but I have no find anything. Feel free to link something If I missed it.

Comment: [This link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/driver-vs-runtime-api.html) supports @talonmies suggestion that implicit context management might be part of your problem.  Particularly the last paragraph about writing plugins and `cudaDeviceReset` affecting future CUDA calls.

Comment: I am going to guess you need to parse the documentation of `mexerrmsgidandtxt` very carefully. It might well be that it does not trigger the necessary lazy context teardown that happens when the equivalent of `std::exit` is called. You might either need something else from matlab to explicitly unload the mex from memory or perform explicit context management yourself. I am going to disagree with @BenVoigt here and suggest this is some specific matlab hebaviour

Comment: @talonmies: No one expects `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt` to cause context teardown.  It just saves an error object which the MATLAB interpreter will look at when it regains control.  It doesn't end the process like `std::exit`.  The point is how to recover from errors without a process restart... and I suspect the answer is the same for any DLL called from a long-running host, no matter which application is the host.  `clear mex` would unload the MEX DLL, which might unload its dependent DLLs, but I'm sure Ander already does `mex clear` when recompiling.

Comment: (I'm using the term DLL, which is fairly Windows-centric, because of the mentions of Visual Studio.  For Linux, think in terms of "shared object" instead)

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed `mex clear` does not do the job. Thank you and @talonmies for the suggestions on the context. I will try to experiment that way see if I can fix it with explicit context management.